# How to deserialize results of Autodesk.Forge.FoldersAPI.GetFolderContentsAsync(...)

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to list the file contents of a given BIM360 folder using the forge .NET client to access the Autodesk's Data Management API.

[GetFolderContents](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/FoldersApi.md#getfoldercontents) returns a JsonApiCollection but I am confused as to how to deserialize the response data using the SDK's model objects.

C# sample code from the documentation:

```cs
// Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: oauth2_access_code
Configuration.Default.AccessToken = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

var apiInstance = new FoldersApi();
var projectId = projectId_example;  // string | the `project id`
var folderId = folderId_example;  // string | the `folder id`
var filterType = new List<string>(); // List<string> | filter by the `type` of the `ref` target (optional)
var filterId = new List<string>(); // List<string> | filter by the `id` of the `ref` target (optional)
var filterExtensionType = new List<string>(); // List<string> | filter by the extension type (optional)
var pageNumber = 56;  // int? | specify the page number (optional)
var pageLimit = 56;  // int? | specify the maximal number of elements per page (optional)

try
{
    JsonApiCollection result = apiInstance.GetFolderContents(projectId, folderId, filterType, filterId, filterExtensionType, pageNumber, pageLimit);
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Print("Exception when calling FoldersApi.GetFolderContents: " + e.Message );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to our [Hubs Browser](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/) tutorial that handles this.

Specificaly in the [Data Browsing](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/data#browsing-hubs) part.

You can also check the [repo](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-hubs-browser-dotnet/blob/develop/Models/APS.Hubs.cs#L51-L55).